# Passportjs local strategy returns 'invalid credentials', is there any way to override this?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

passport has been a real thorn in my side lately. I'm trying to register a user and have a custom callback. However, if the user doesn't supply a username and password and just submits the form I get back an 'invalid credentials' error. I would like to intercept this before then so I can format it like the rest of my error messages, and send it back.

Is there any way to do this? I dug through passport and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make that happen on the callback, look at this example (not pretty code but it illustrates the idea well). In this case, if the user credentials are valid but the user has not confirmed their email address, I am returning a flash object to notify the user of the error. You could also make user of the `/success` or `/failure` options on passport to call specific url's upon a success or failure of authentication.

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
      passport.authenticate('local', function(error, user, info){
        if(error){
            //handle error here
        }
        else{
          if(!user){
            res.status(404).end();
          } else{
            req.logIn(user, function(error){
              if(error) return res.status(500).end();
              if(!user.isEmailConfirmed){
                  req.session.flash = {
                      type: 'warning',
                      intro: 'Achtung',
                      message: 'error message'
                  };
                  res.redirect('/');
              }
              else res.redirect('/');
            });
          }
        }
      })(req, res, next);
    });
```